# Mapeamento 1 para 0, 0 para 1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou precisando criar um mapeamento entre duas entidades existentes, onde ambas são independentes.

Então.

Tenho uma entidade `DepositoTransferencia` e a outra é `Conta`. A ideia é que em determinado momento, os registros da entidade `DepositoTransferencia` estejam associados uma única vez em `Conta`, mas em um primeiro momento não.
Mas os registros de `Conta` não necessariamente estejam relacionados com `DepositoTransferencia`.

O que irá acontecer a nível de sistema é o seguinte: um usuário irá cadastrar os depósitos/transferências e outro usuário irá confirmar esse lançamento, no que ele confirmar esse lançamento, o sistema tem que disponibilizar o valor do depósito/transferência na conta do usuário que cadastrou.

O que eu fiz:

```
[Table("DepositosTransferencias")]
public class DepositoTransferencia : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid DepositoTransferenciaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Conta bancária")]
    public int ContaBancoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ContaBancoId))]
    public virtual ContaBanco ContaBanco { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Número")]
    public string NumeroComprovante { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Número no extrato")]
    public string NumeroExtrato { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Data")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DataDocumento { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Required]        
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data de liberação")]
    public DateTime? DataLiberacao { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Observação")]
    public string Observacao { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Tipo")]
    public DepositoTransferenciaTipo Tipo { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(DepositoTransferenciaSituacao.DepositoTransferencia))]
    public virtual ICollection<DepositoTransferenciaSituacao> DepositosTransferenciasSituacoes { get; set; }


}

[Table("Contas")]
public partial class Conta
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ContaId { get; set; }
}

[Table("DepositosTransferenciasContas")]
public class DepositoTransferenciaConta
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(DepositoTransferencia))]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public Guid DepositoTransferenciaId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Conta))]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public int ContaId { get; set; }

    public virtual DepositoTransferencia DepositoTransferencia { get; set; }

    public virtual Conta Conta { get; set; }
}
```

Minha dúvida é:

- Se o que eu fiz estaria certo.
- Como eu declararia as propriedades inversas em
  `DepositoTransferencia` e `Conta`
- ou que outra abordagem eu poderia usar para tal questão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você criou a entidade **DepositoTransferenciaConta** pra intermediar a ligação entre **DepositoTransferencia** e **Conta**, porém, pelo o que entendi da sua regra: *"um usuário irá cadastrar os depósitos/transferências e outro usuário irá confirmar esse lançamento, no que ele confirmar esse lançamento, o sistema tem que disponibilizar o valor do depósito/transferência na conta do usuário que cadastrou."*, não visualizei a necessidade de uma ligação de muitos pra muitos entre essas duas entidades. Visualizo o banco dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma, quando cadastrar o depósito a conta já estará associada e com o campo confirmado você consegue saber se foi aceito ou não aquele deposito.

O campo **confirmado** pode ser trocado por um campo **status** caso necessite de outros status para o seu deposito, além do de confirmação.

Comment: Na realidade o que eu quero é uma relação de 1 para 1 entre DepositoTransferencia e Conta, por isso que criei a tabela de ligação, onde nas colunas `ContaId` e `DepositoTransferenciaId` são definidas como Unique. Porém podem existir dados em Conta que não existam em DepositoTransferencia, assim como podem existir dados em DepositoTransferencia que não existam em Conta.
Da forma como você propõem, eu teria uma relação de 1 para N entre Conta e DepositoTransferencia

Comment: Sempre que você fizer um depósito ele precisará ser associado com a conta, certo ? Existe um depósito que nao tem conta ?

Comment: Sim, só irá para a conta após a confirmação, se ele não for confirmado, não irá existir na conta.

Comment: As duas solução resolvem o problema. A diferença é que na sua solucão a confirmação de pagamento é feita através de outra tabela, na minha, a confirmação está na própria entidade depósito. 

Eu faria da forma como apresentei, porque não precisa de JOIN/SUBQUERY pra saber quais depósitos foram confirmados em uma determinada conta.